# How to implement an equation with "diag" and circled-times symbol (⊗) in Python

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

[image]

The above equation is found in this paper (https://openreview.net/pdf?id=Sk_P2Q9sG) as equation #4.

I'm really confused as to how this gets converted into the following code:

```
epistemic = np.mean(p_hat**2, axis=0) - np.mean(p_hat, axis=0)**2
aleatoric = np.mean(p_hat*(1-p_hat), axis=0)
```

I think I may be confused due to the symbols in the equation though, for instance "diag" and the circle with a cross in it. How is the diag and circle represented as such in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what those symbols mean in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The linked article explains below eq. (2) the definition of this "outer square" operation:

v<sup>⊗2</sup> = v v<sup>T</sup>.

In the field of machine learning, vectors are to be interpreted as column vectors. In numpy, if `v` is a vector of shape `(n,)`, you would write:

```
v.reshape(-1, 1) * v
```

The result is a shape `(n, n)` array. If you want to stay closer to the notation with column and row vectors, you could also write:

```
v_column = v.reshape(-1, 1)
result = v_column @ v_column.T
```

The function `diag` is the same as `np.diag`: you feed it a vector and you get a diagonal matrix.

How the Python snippet in your question implements the equations from the paper is hard to tell without information about what the shape of `p_hat` is and which axis represents `t` in the equation. In the most plausible definition, `p_hat` would have shape `(T, n)`, in which case `np.mean(p_hat**2, axis=0)` would return shape `(n,)`, which is not consistent with the equation that you quoted from the paper that should result in an `(n, n)` shape.

Given that the epistemic and aleatoric uncertainties in the paper seem to be scalars rather than vectors, I suspect that the authors made an error in the definition of the ⊗2 exponent: they should have written

v<sup>⊗2</sup> = v<sup>T</sup> v

which translates to Python (on shape `(n,)` arrays) as

```
np.sum(v**2)
```